# Continue Asterisk Dial Plan after Wild Card Match

Tags: asterisk, voip

I have a working Asterisk 13 Dialplan where a call goes into extensions.conf and then within extensions.conf into a switch statement:

```
switch => Realtime
```

That works.  The call completes based on the content of the database table.

Now what I want to do is a little filtering before the call goes to the Realtime table.  Something like this:

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(GROUP()=${ACCOUNTCODE:0:4})
exten => _X.,n,GotoIf($[${GROUP_COUNT(ABCD)} > 2]?tooMany,1)
exten => _X.,n,Log(VERBOSE,Call Continuing.  ${ACCOUNTCODE} is not a limited group)
switch => Realtime

exten => tooMany,1,Congestion(4)
exten => tooMany,n,hangup(503)
```

BUT, what seems to happen is that once the extension matches (the _X.) the processing continues through the match but does not continue and process the "switch => Realtime" line (it never executes the database component of the dialplan)

How do I get the Realtime dialplan to execute after going through the filter?

- Second somewhat related question

Incidentally, I can have a similar problem in an all-text extensions.conf where I want all calls to have something done to them, and then do something specific to certain calls.  e.g.

```
exten => _X.,1,<do something>
exten => 1122,1,<do some more stuff to the same call>
```

This is treated in the documentation and 1122 is the more specific line and will be the one executed.  BUT, what is the correct way of doing something to all calls AND then do the specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you not understand how switch Realtime works.

It is not possible do switch for one extensions(or pattern) only. It is possible do for CONTEXT. When asterisk engine see switch=>realtime it works like include, i.e include database search in this WHOLE context.

You also seams like not understanding how dialplan works(otherwise will be no question 2). Please read book like ORelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony", it have step-by-step description of how that works.

Comment: That would be fine if it worked like an include, EXCEPT that IF the EXTEN matches the pattern it NEVER goes to the switch/database search.  Why is that?

Comment: BECAUSE IT IS SWITCH. If you want additional extensions in same context, you should do include =>someothecontext and do switch in someothercontext.